# Which version of Supee-8788 required for C.E 1.9.0.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

My magento instance is C.E  - 1.9.0.1

And at my instance Supee-8788 not installed Yet.

So, i want to know which Supee-8788 version need to  be install  for my instance ? V1 or V2!!

Magento download only give us to  download supee-8788-V2.

Currently my system have below patches:

- SUPEE-5344
- SUPEE-1533
- SUPEE-5998
- SUPEE-6285
- SUPEE-6482

**My question is which patch are required to install at C.E. -1.9.0.1**

- **SUPEE-3941 is required to installed ?**
- **SUPEE-8788 v1 is required to installed ?**
- **SUPEE-8788 v2 is required to installed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply patch SUPEE-3941 followed by SUPEE-8788 V2. You should be all set!

Comment: Aha. Paras sood.. it is working